# Sort activities in a related list by a specific column

Tags: related-list, configuration

I have a page layout for a custom object. I have a related list on that page layout. The related list is open activities. Is it possible to sort the records in the related list by any column? Currently it is being sorted by the due date of the task. However, I have a new customer field called item number which I want to sort by.

Answer (score 4):

Currently its not possible to sort open activites.Here is the idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqX6AAK

Workaround : Create a list button on Task

with URL value as /007?id={!Account.Id}&rlid=RelatedActivityList

[image]

Add the button to Open Activities Related list of Account Pagelayout.Then on Click of button it will open new page where you could sort open activities on any field.